# VBA MkDir silently removes caron

Tags: vba, character-encoding

I am using VBA to create folders automatically. One of the folder names that I need to create contains the character č (c with caron). When I use MkDir in VBA the folder is created with a "c" instead of a "č".

Sample code:

```
root_folder = "C:\customers\"
folder_name = "háček" 'I do not think you can enter this into the VBA editor, but I am getting the folder_name from an external source
full_folder_path = root_folder & folder_name & "\"
MkDir full_folder_path
attachment.SaveAs full_folder_path & attachment.filename
```

This will create a folder called "C:\customers\hacek\" instead of "C:\customers\háček\", which then causes the save operation to fail, because it tries to save in "C:\customers\háček\, which of course does not exist. VBA seems to be able to read and handle the characters correctly, because I can read it from my data source and save it to a text file without issues. The problem just seems to exist when it comes to creating folders.

Is there a way to make VBA create the folder with the name that I have actually specified?

---

edit: formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `FileSystemObject`, you are able to create the Folder with the proper name:

```
Dim fs As Object

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fs.CreateFolder "C:\customers\hac" & ChrW(269) & "ek" 'ChrW(269) prints č
```